# Why can't I rename this object in my node application?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I've got a node.js/express application communicating with a Postgres database using the [node-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) module. It's working with async/await, but if I rename the object being returned to anything other than **{ rows }**, it comes back undefined. Here is my code; note the comment right under the `async`, and above `const { rows } = ...`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: 'postgresql://postgres@localhost/mydb'
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  (async () => {
    // if I rename this from "rows" to, say, "userdetails", it comes back undefined
    const { rows } = await pool.query(`
            SELECT id, password
            FROM myschema.users
            WHERE username = $1
            LIMIT 1;`,[username]);

    if (rows.length) {
      // check password, etc, etc.
      return res.status(200).send();
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send();
    }      
  })().catch(e => setImmediate(() => { 
    res.status(500);
    } 
  ));

});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm sure I'm missing something pretty basic here, but why can't I rename this? Does the pg module dictate somehow that the returned var/const must be named `{ rows }`? If so, how might I discover that? I set a breakpoint at the `await` and step through the code, but it's still unclear to me.

Comment: Just in case, are you renaming all instances of the rows variable to your new variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `const { rows } = xxx`, you are using [object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to assign the `xxx.rows` property to a new variable in the local scope that has the same name as the property.

Thus when you change the name of that property to something else:

```
const { myVar } = xxx;
```

The code is now looking for the property `xxx.myVar` which likely does not exist and thus ends up `undefined`.

If you want to use a different name, then you have to either use a different form of object destructuring assignment (that includes a new name) or don't use destructuring at all and just assign the `.rows` property to a new variable.

For example, you could do this instead:

```
const result = await pool.query(`
            SELECT id, password
            FROM myschema.users
            WHERE username = $1
            LIMIT 1;`,[username]);

const myVar = result.rows;
```

Or you could designate a new name in the object destructuring assignment:

```
const {rows: myVar} = await pool.query(`
            SELECT id, password
            FROM myschema.users
            WHERE username = $1
            LIMIT 1;`,[username]);

console.log(myVar);
```

Comment: Thanks. Listing the alternatives was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [`Object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). When you do something like this

```
const { row } = someObject
```

then the variable `row` is equal to the `row property of someObject`. But if `someObject` does not even have any `row` property, then `row` obviously will be `undefined`.

Same is happening in your case. The object returned by `await pool.query(...` have `rows` property, thats why `const { rows }` works but it does not have `userdetails` property hence `undefined`.